# Get frequency of sentence tokens (instead of words) by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a pandas column, which is titles for online shopping products, classified by categories:

```
df

category    title 
electronics ALLDOCUBE iPlay 7T 4G LTE Kids Tablet 6.98" HD iPS Android 9.0 Tablets 16GB ROM Support 256G Expansion Dual Ai 4 Core Type C GPS
electronics Alldocube iPlay8 pro 8 inch Tablet Android 9.0 MTK MT8321 Quad core 3G Calling Tablet PC RAM 2GB ROM 32GB 800*1280 IPS OTG
accessories Alldocube iPlay10 Pro 10.1 inch Wifi Tablet  Android 9.0  MT8163  quad core 1200*1920 IPS Tablets PC RAM 3GB ROM 32GB HDMI OTG
clothing    ALLDOCUBE iPlay10 Pro Tablet 10.1 3GB RAM 32GB ROM Android 9.0 MT8163 Quad Core Tablet PC 1920 x 1200 IPS 6600mAh Wifi Tablet
```

I tokenized the title columns by words and it succeed (returns lists of words)

```
df['tokenized_text'] = df['title'].str.lower().apply(word_tokenize)

df.tokenized_text

0 [naviforce, men, watches, waterproof, stainless, steel, quartz, watch, male, chronograph, military, clock, wrist, watch, relogio, masculino]
1 [curren, 8291, luxury, brand, men, analog, digital, leather, sports, watches, men, 's, army, military, watch, man, quartz, clock, relogio, masculino]
2 [pagani, design, brand, luxury, men, watches, automatic, black, watch, men, stainless, steel, waterproof, business, sport, mechanical, wristwatch]
```

My main goal is to get tokens frequency by category, I did it with words tokens, but I can't did it for sentences

**This is the code for frequencies by category for words**:

```
f = lambda x: nltk.FreqDist([w for wordlist in x for w in wordlist])
df_frequency = df.groupby('category')['tokenized_text'].apply(f).reset_index()

df_frequency.sample(5)
        category    level_1     tokenized_text
28230   shoesbags   passport    13.0
8534    electronics dvb         2.0
33509   womencloth  short       1.0
19357   homeimprov  bakelite    1.0
26677   momkids     suits       33.0
```

I want to do the same for sentences instead of just words
I tried to tokenize the title column by sentences by return the whole title as sentence

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

df['tokenized_sent'] = df['title'].str.lower().apply(sent_tokenize)

df['tokenized_sent'].sample(5)
1812 [10pcs brass micro pave cubic zirconia flower bead caps for jewelry making diy bracelet necklace findings 12x4mm hole: 1mm]
2509 [car seat covers set universal fit most cars covers with tire track detail styling car seat protector four seasons for seats]
6416 [dhroom black and white beautiful flower canvas posters and prints minimalist painting wall art decorative picture home decor]
198  [en bohemian natural shell conch rope anklets for women foot jewelry summer beach barefoot bracelet ankle on leg for women]
9100 [2020 summer shoes women sandals holiday beach wedges sandals women slippers soft comfortable ladies summer slippers a2121]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because for the **sent_tokenize** function you don't have more than one sentence (at least in the samples you share). The [sent_tokenize](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html#sent_tokenize) function use the [PunktSentenceTokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer) implementation for splitting and this implementation use the punctuation symbols (';', ':', ',', '.', '!', '?') to find sentences boundaries.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

sent_tokenize("This is a sentence, this is another sentence")
['This is a sentence, this is another sentence']

sent_tokenize("This is a sentence? I think here is another")
['This is a sentence?', 'I think here is another']
```

Depending of your goal you can divide your text into [n-grams](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-split-a-string-into-n-grams-in-python), which are a set of n consecutive words among the text.

```
from nltk import ngrams

title = 'ALLDOCUBE iPlay 7T 4G LTE Kids Tablet 6.98" HD iPS Android 9.0 Tablets 16GB ROM Support 256G Expansion Dual Ai 4 Core Type C GPS'
words = title.split()
# Splitting in sentences of 5 words
fifth_grams = ngrams(words,5)
fifth_grams_list = [list(gram) for gram in fifth_grams]
sentences = [' '.join(word for word in gram) for gram in fifth_grams_list]

for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)

ALLDOCUBE iPlay 7T 4G LTE
iPlay 7T 4G LTE Kids
7T 4G LTE Kids Tablet
4G LTE Kids Tablet 6.98"
LTE Kids Tablet 6.98" HD
Kids Tablet 6.98" HD iPS
Tablet 6.98" HD iPS Android
6.98" HD iPS Android 9.0
HD iPS Android 9.0 Tablets
iPS Android 9.0 Tablets 16GB
Android 9.0 Tablets 16GB ROM
9.0 Tablets 16GB ROM Support
Tablets 16GB ROM Support 256G
16GB ROM Support 256G Expansion
ROM Support 256G Expansion Dual
Support 256G Expansion Dual Ai
256G Expansion Dual Ai 4
Expansion Dual Ai 4 Core
Dual Ai 4 Core Type
Ai 4 Core Type C
4 Core Type C GPS
```

On the other hand, check if there is a fixed position where you want to make the split.